# SQL Server : how do I read the last character of a string, and add a new character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to read a string and if there is no `,` (comma) at the end of that string add a `,` (comma) to end of it.

```
@customernumber='583473,789458'
```

after system checking there is no comma add `,` (comma) and make it like below

```
@customernumber='583473,789458,'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to store multiple *numeric* customer numbers in a string.  That is a bad idea, and you should think hard about alternatives.

But the answer to your question is:

```
set @customernumber = (case when @customernumber like '%,' then @customernumber
                            else @customernumber + ','
                       end)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, could you please tell me if im storing almost 800 character   (around 50 different customer number) is it taking long time to check this? at the moment im having a problem my system sometimes add ,(comma) to end of it and sometimes not. so i had to come up with idea of checking string before adding it into the system.

Comment: @WineTapasBar . . . As I say in the answer, this is probably a bad database design.